# export a relational Snowflake table as valid JSON or XML

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake and want to export it as JSON or XML but am struggling to get all of the records from my table into one valid output. I'm not very familiar with JSON formats but have made some progress.

Here is a sample of my table:

| USER_ID | PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID | PRODUCT_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "1770607c104641caaf5fde0e433b76a6" | ["817720022911","817720022782"] | [39.99,39.99] |
| "27d4c6a6559e48629dc558c94080c5ca" | ["882709630449" ] | [43.65 ] |

Here is the query I am using to get the results below:

```
create or replace temp table json_output as 
with cte as
(
select  
to_json(
      object_construct('order_details', 
array_agg(
                                                   object_construct('user_id', user_id,
                                                                    'PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID',PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID,
                                                                    'PRODUCT_PRICE',PRODUCT_PRICE
                                                                    )                 
                                                   )
                     )
    )as output  
from one_row_per_order 
group by user_id
)
 
select  * 
from    cte;
```

When querying the above table, this is the format of the JSON (both records combined):

```
{
    "order_details": [{
        "PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID": ["817720022911", "817720022782"],
        "PRODUCT_PRICE": [   39.99,   39.99 ],
        "USER_ID": "1770607c104641caaf5fde0e433b76a6",
    }]
} {
        "PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID": [   "882709630449" ],
        "PRODUCT_PRICE": [   43.65 ],
        "USER_ID": "27d4c6a6559e48629dc558c94080c5ca"
    }]
}
```

However, from my understanding the above isn't valid JSON - see the where the first object ends and the next begins (the first close-square-bracket is in the wrong place). Instead, this is my desired output format (valid JSON syntax) but I can't achieve it:

```
{
    "order_details": [{
        "PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID": ["12345", "26810"],
        "PRODUCT_PRICE": [17.99, 10.99],
        "USER_ID": "1770607c104641caaf5fde0e433b76a6"
    }, 
    {
        "PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID": ["4578", "9876", "8888"],
        "PRODUCT_PRICE": [4.99, 12.50],
        "USER_ID": "27d4c6a6559e48629dc558c94080c5ca"
    }]
}
```

I have tried array_agg but reach the maximum size limit imposed by LOB objects in Snowflake (I actually have 70k records my table with many more columns than shown in the example).I also tried TO_XML but ran into the same issue where each row is treated as an object where I want all rows combined into one object.

Have you any suggestions as to how to format the JSON please? As mentioned, I would accept valid XML too.

Comment: can you please include data as text rather then image in your question.

Comment: @the_james Are you sure that there are not 2 separate records for 1770607c104641caaf5fde0e433b76a6? Is your sample data the aggregated version?

Comment: @GokhanAtil - I could normalize the data so there are two separate records for 1770607c104641caaf5fde0e433b76a6, if that would help but I think we'd still run into similar issues as far as I can see

Answer (score 0):

Original Table -

```
select * from test_json;
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| USER_ID             | PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID | PRODUCT_PRICE |
|---------------------+---------------------+---------------|
| 1770607c90283414343 | [                   | [             |
|                     |   "817823487432",   |   39.99,      |
|                     |   "817982433987"    |   39.99       |
|                     | ]                   | ]             |
| 27d4c90283414343    | [                   | [             |
|                     |   "882487432"       |   43.65       |
|                     | ]                   | ]             |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

Query to return valid JSON, as converted from values in table; however, we still have limits for size as imposed in snowflake for various functions such as ARRAY_AGG -

```
select object_construct('order_details',array_agg(json_1)) as json_val
from
(
select '1' as id,
OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID',
PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID,
'PRODUCT_PRICE',
PRODUCT_PRICE,
'USER_ID',user_id) as json_1
from test_json)
group by id;
+----------------------------------------+
| JSON_VAL                               |
|----------------------------------------|
| {                                      |
|   "order_details": [                   |
|     {                                  |
|       "PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID": [         |
|         "817823487432",                |
|         "817982433987"                 |
|       ],                               |
|       "PRODUCT_PRICE": [               |
|         39.99,                         |
|         39.99                          |
|       ],                               |
|       "USER_ID": "1770607c90283414343" |
|     },                                 |
|     {                                  |
|       "PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID": [         |
|         "882487432"                    |
|       ],                               |
|       "PRODUCT_PRICE": [               |
|         43.65                          |
|       ],                               |
|       "USER_ID": "27d4c90283414343"    |
|     }                                  |
|   ]                                    |
| }                                      |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Another approach (which though does not meet 'combine all' requirement), is load all records as JSON in JSON format stage file and then we can use that as needed.
As per below test case - for 70K record the input bytes will be around 14MB.

```
create stage test_int_stage file_format=(type=JSON);
+-------------------------------------------------+
| status                                          |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| Stage area TEST_INT_STAGE successfully created. |
+-------------------------------------------------+

copy into @TEST_INT_STAGE from (select
(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID',
PRODUCT_EXTERNAL_ID,
'PRODUCT_PRICE',
PRODUCT_PRICE,
'USER_ID',user_id)) as json_col
from test_json);
+---------------+-------------+--------------+
| rows_unloaded | input_bytes | output_bytes |
|---------------+-------------+--------------|
|             2 |         209 |          143 |
+---------------+-------------+--------------+

list @test_int_stage;
+-----------------------------------+------+
| name                              | size |
|-----------------------------------+------+
| test_int_stage/data_0_0_0.json.gz |  144 |
+-----------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the structure is exactly what I want. However, is there any way around the limits for size imposed by array_agg? Otherwise unfortunately the solution won't work for me given my table size

Comment: I believe the limit is imposed as per snowflake, which is 16MB for semi-structured data-type - array, object, variant